# First isomorphism theorem with sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I have the following here:

> Let $R=\text{Map}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ with addition and multiplication defined, as usual, by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(f \cdot g)(x)=f(x)g(x)$. Let $S$ be the ring of sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ with entries $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, and define:
> $$\varphi: R \rightarrow S$$
> $$f \mapsto (f(n))_n$$
> a) Show that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism.
> b) Use the First Isomorphism Theorem to show that there is a well-defined ring isomorphism $\overline{\varphi}:R/I \rightarrow S$ satisfying $\overline{\varphi}(f+i)=(f(n))_n$ for all $f\in R$, where $I=\{f\in R|f(n)=0 \text{ for all } n\in N\}$.
> c)Let $1\in R$ be the constant function $\mathbf{1}:x \mapsto 1.$ Find a non-constant function $f\in R$ such that $f+I=\mathbf{1}+I$.

a) I got this. It was fine.

b) I know the first isomorphism theorem implies that:

$\frac{R}{\text{ker}(\varphi)}\rightarrow\text{Image}(\varphi)$

$a+\text{ker}(\varphi) \mapsto\varphi(a)$

I'm not really sure how to use this though. It seems almost too simple. I know here the image is $S$ and the kernel is $I$. So does that mean I just need to write:

$\frac{R}{I} \rightarrow S$

$f+I \mapsto (f(n))_n$ ?

I'm not 100% sure about this part. It seems too simple.

I am not sure if I am understanding how to actually "write" the first isomorphism theorem correctly.

c) I know that $f+I=\mathbf{1}+I$ implies $f-\mathbf{1} \in I$ so could I not just pick $f=f(n)-1$ as my function? Again, I'm not 100% sure about this part.

Comment: If you show that $\ker \varphi = I$ and that $\text{im }\varphi = S$ then the isomorphism is given by the First Isomorphism Theorem. For c) how can you pick $f = f(n) - 1$? $f$ is not given so you cannot use it.

Comment: Did I not already show this though? This map is clearly surjective since the result of the transformation describes all of $S$. The kernel implies that $\varphi{f}=0$ so, $(f(n))_n=0$ so every term is 0. This means the original function $f$ must have been $0$ so there is a kernel given by $I$ as defined.

Where does the $\overline{\varphi}(f+i)=(f(n))_n$ for all $f\in R$ come into play though? I don't see it.

c) I picked it because I'm not what else to do. I know I need to show that $f-\mathbf{1}$ is in $I$ which means that since $f(n)=0$ for all the natural numbers, $f$ is -1?

Comment: For c) try $f(x) = \chi_{\mathbb{N}}(x)$. For b) you have shown it yeah. The map is precisely the one given in the proof of the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Sorry what is $f(x) = \chi_{\mathbb{N}}(x)$ ? The notation isn't familiar to me.

Comment: The [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) of $\mathbb N\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It's the indicator function of $\mathbb{N}$ ie. $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0$ otherwise.